# Code Analysis missing from Visual Studio 2008

Tags: visual-studio-2008

I have just installed Visual Studio 2008 on a Virtual PC to evaluate it and one of the features I want to try out is the Code Analysis.

However I can't seem to find it anywhere, on [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/e05a02t4.aspx) it says you can right click on a project  and select properties and then simply enable it from there. However I don't see this option anywhere.

At first I thought it may be because I converted a 2005 ASP.NET project targeting .NET 2.0 however as a Test I created a dummy 3.5 project but with still no luck

Has anyone else come across this?

EDIT: I am currently using Visual Studio 2008 SP1 and working on VB.NET/ASP.NET projects

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Code Analysis is only in the Team System versions of Visual Studio.  All others only come with unit testing.

Comment: And here I had Visual Studio 2010 Professional Edition installed. What was I thinking!

Answer (score 4):

Code Analysis is only in [some editions](http://www.microsoft.com/visualstudio/en-us/products/teamsystem/default.mspx#compare_products).

An old version of code analysis, FxCop, is still a [free download](http://www.microsoft.com/Downloads/details.aspx?FamilyID=3389f7e4-0e55-4a4d-bc74-4aeabb17997b&displaylang=en).

Answer (score 2):

Are you evaluating a Professional or a larger (i.e. Team System) edition? As far as I know, Code Analysis is simply not included in Professional and smaller editions.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that the code analysis is only removed from the GUI of these Visual Studio versions. 

When using Visual Studio Express 2008, and the project file contains under the sections 

`<PropertyGroup Condition=" '$(Configuration)|$(Platform)' == ...`
the line 

**`<RunCodeAnalysis>true</RunCodeAnalysis>`**

the code analysis will run for corresponding project configuration. 

On my machine, that means that file at
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 9.0\Team Tools\Static Analysis Tools\FxCop\FxCopCmd.exe
is being executed with a lot of arguments and its output is automatically directed into warnings pane. 

So, maybe the **FxCop** has to be separately installed, but besides that even the **VS Express** seems to support the code analysis tool.